# List aliases, and recursion-like behaviour between lists referencing each other

Tags: python, list

I've recently been very confused with list aliasing and how exactly it works. I know that when append a list b directly into a another list a, modifying the part of list a that is connected to list b will modify list b as well.
However, I'm not very sure how to explain it in that context when running this script in my Jupyter Notebook; I don't seem to get how

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
a.append(b)
print(a[3][1])
b.append(a)
print(b[2][1])
a[3][1] = 6
print(a[3][2] is a)
print(b[2][3][2] == a)
```

outputs

```
5
2
True
True
```

Furthermore, when I

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

I get the interesting results:
`[1, 2, 3, [4, 6, [...]]]` and `[4, 6, [1, 2, 3, [...]]]`... It is as if the lists get into a recursive state where they contain each other.

I expected correctly that by changing appending `a` to `b` after appending `b` to `a` that it would result in some self interreferencing loop (at least that is what it seems like) where `a` contains `b` but at the same time `b` contains `a`, but I have no idea how to explain this.

Comment: Yes, your lists contain each other - because that's exactly what you told Python to do.  What outcome were you expecting?

Comment: @jasonharper I guess I was expecting exactly that, but I think there is a difference between expecting it based on intuition, and knowing exactly what is going on. For instance, what exactly is going on when Jupyter outputs ... in the place of the list? I am still unsure what goes in those ellipses

Comment: `[...]` represents a list that has already started to be printed out, but has been encountered again before the original printout finished.  It's `a` when you're printing `a`, `b` when you're printing `b`.  (If Python *didn't* recognize and specially handle this situation, it would crash trying to produce an infinitely-long string representation of the object.)

Comment: ahh thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explain this with the concept of mutable/immutable data types, and pointers.

Whenever you create a variable and assign it a value, it is stored in memory (RAM) at a specific address.

The general concept of immutable data types is that they cannot be changed (at least on the same address).

In python, a string is an immutable data type. Let's perform an experiment. Let's take a string, and get its address (using built in [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function). Then we modify it, and then get the same variable's `id` again:

```
# Initialise a string and print its ID
some_str = "Hello"
print("The variable value:", some_str)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_str))
print("#" * 10)

# Change the string and print its ID
some_str += " World"
print("The variable value:", some_str)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_str))
print("#" * 10)
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
The variable value: Hello
Variable's ID: 4457023280
##########
The variable value: Hello World
Variable's ID: 4458388464
##########
```

As you can see, even though the variable is the same, its `id` is different now after mutation. This means that even though it seems like the same variable was modified, that wasn't the case. Actually, a new variable in memory was created and the variable started pointing to that.

In python, list is a mutable data type, which means you should be able to modify it at the same memory address (`id`). Lets try doing the same with a list now:

```
# Initialise a list and print its ID
some_list = ["Hello"]
print("The variable value:", some_list)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_list))
print("#" * 10)

# Change the list and print its ID
some_list.append("World")
print("The variable value:", some_list)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_list))
print("#" * 10)
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
The variable value: ['Hello']
Variable's ID: 4484419200
##########
The variable value: ['Hello', 'World']
Variable's ID: 4484419200
##########
```

As you can see, even though the list was changed, its ID remained the same - it is mutable.

Lets keep this concept in mind and move forward.

In python, when you append a variable to a list (or even assign a variable to another variable e.g. `a = b`), python doesn't assign the value. Instead it just points to the `id` of the variable. Lets do another experiment:

```
# Initialise a string and print its ID
some_str = "Hello"
print("The variable value:", some_str)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_str))
print("#" * 10)

# Initialise a list and print its ID
some_list_1 = ["Hello"]
print("The variable value:", some_list_1)
print("Variable's ID:", id(some_list_1))
print("#" * 10)

# Initialise an empty list and append above two, and then print the list items' IDs
some_list_2 = []
some_list_2.append(some_str)
some_list_2.append(some_list_1)

print("List's first element:", some_list_2[0])
print("ID of the first element:", id(some_list_2[0]))
print("ID of the first element equals some_str?:", id(some_list_2[0]) == id(some_str))
print("*" * 10)
print("List's second element:", some_list_2[1])
print("ID of the second element:", id(some_list_2[1]))
print("ID of the second element equals some_list_1?:", id(some_list_2[1]) == id(some_list_1))
print("*" * 10)

# Now we change some_str and some_list, and check the list elements' IDs again.
some_str += " World"
print("ID of some_str now:", id(some_str))  # This would be different, pointing to a different ID
some_list_1.append("World")
print("ID of some_list_1 now:", id(some_list_1))  # This would be the same
print("#" * 10)

print("List's first element:", some_list_2[0])
print("ID of the first element:", id(some_list_2[0]))  # This would still be pointing to the previous id
print("ID of the first element equals some_str?:", id(some_list_2[0]) == id(some_str))
print("*" * 10)
print("List's second element:", some_list_2[1])
print("ID of the second element:", id(some_list_2[1]))  # This would still be pointing to the previous id
print("ID of the second element equals some_list_1?:", id(some_list_2[1]) == id(some_list_1))
print("*" * 10)
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
The variable value: Hello
Variable's ID: 4321089264
##########
The variable value: ['Hello']
Variable's ID: 4322442880
##########
List's first element: Hello
ID of the first element: 4321089264
ID of the first element equals some_str?: True
**********
List's second element: ['Hello']
ID of the second element: 4322442880
ID of the second element equals some_list_1?: True
**********
ID of some_str now: 4322509360
ID of some_list_1 now: 4322442880
##########
List's first element: Hello
ID of the first element: 4321089264
ID of the first element equals some_str?: False
**********
List's second element: ['Hello', 'World']
ID of the second element: 4322442880
ID of the second element equals some_list_1?: True
**********
```

Now as you can see, when we appended the two items to `some_list_2` initially, it stored their reference and not the value. When the list `some_list_1` was modified, you can see the change reflected in `some_list_2` as well because `some_list_1` was changed at its memory address, which `some_list_2[1]` was pointing to.

Hope this helps!